# Changing the content in a table cell in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, report

Trying to changing the content in a table cell that gets its data in an  Angular fashion. Not sure what use to place a link when a certain string happens. This is the pseudo-code-ish idea.

```
<td>{{ e.training }}</td>
        <td class="regSale">
            <script>
                if ({{ e.tranTypeId}} == "regularSale") {              document.getElementsByClassName("regSale").innerHTML = placeLinkHere;              } else {document.getElementsByClassName("regSale").innerHTML = hello;}
            </script>
        </td>
        <td>{{ e.userId }}</td>
```

Here is what I tried in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XGgVvmW7ynqI0OifvqeR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to get references to other elements in Angular. Instead just use value bindings and properties in your controller for display and functional purposes.

Also you are using `<script>` tags inside places where the angular could possibly render, just put this functionality in the controller.

In your plunker example you have not (or deleted my mistake) the script that includes the main script:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Here is a forked version of your example with the main errors fixed, you can see the values displayed:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aGuBPNdhhHt1uH8uM4Ng?p=preview

Comment: In this example, not sure how to use value bindings and properties in the controller. I move this code to the controller. Didn't work out.  as this..    $scope.elements = $scope.result.data.transactionList.map(function (res) {
  var e = {};
  e.tranTypeId = res.tranTypeId;
  e.userId = res.userId;
  e.storeId = res.storeId;
  e.lookUpLink =  if ({{ e.tranTypeId}} == "regularSale") {  
    document.getElementsByClassName("regSale").innerHTML = <a href="">LookUpLink</a>;          }
    else {document.getElementsByClassName("regSale").innerHTML = hello;}
  return e;
});